# Order of success callbacks when promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

When there's a piece of code that depends on data prepared by other promises, do I have to create additional helper promises:

```
    var dfd1,dfd2;
    dfd1 = $q.defer();
    dfd2 = $q.defer();
    Service1.queryAll().then(function(data) {
        // prepare data 1
        dfd1.resolve();
    });

    Service2.queryAll().then(function(data) {
        // prepare data 2
        dfd2 .resolve();
    });

    $q.all([dfd1.promise,dfd2.promise]).then(function() {
        // use data 1 & 2
    })
```

or can I use promises returned by `queryAll()` call in `$q.all` ?

I mean: will callback in `$q.all` execute after previous success callbacks finish, or there could be the case then `$q.all` callback will execute before `Service1` and `Service2` success callbacks finish execution?

Comment: Promise callbacks are always invoked in the order in which they were registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `$q`. Here's an example:

```
var p1 = Service1.queryAll();

var p2 = p1.then(function (response) { ... });

//Everything chained to p1 will resolve BEFORE p2 is executed.
//Naturally everything chained to p2 will execute after p1 and p2.
```

You can think of promises like event handlers. By calling `.then` you append another event handler to the event.

When p1 resolves it loops every event handler registered to it and executes it:

```
//Inside promise implementation
var eventHandlers = [];

this.then = function(fn){
 eventHandlers.push(fn);
 if(!this.executed)
  this.execute();
}

function whenResolved(data){
 eventHandlers.forEach(function(fn){
  fn(data);
 });
}
```

Note: this is not the actual way this works since even when the promise is resolved you still execute newly registered event handlers but you might get a better understanding of how this works.